# SQL Server Management Studio - upgrade to Windows 10 fails

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

All was well under Windows 7 Pro but after upgrading to Windows 10 I now cannot connect to my local instance - but I can connect to my server.

Comment: can you post the error?  Also, are you sure your local instance of SQL Server is running?

Comment: screenshot of error please.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your instance is still stuck in setup mode

```
Command Line Startup Parameters: -s "MSSQLSERVER" -m "SqlSetup" -T 4022 -T 4010 -T 1905 -T 3701 -T 8015
```

Have a look at the following SO to see if it helps: [Can't get SQL Server to start or connect to my local database engine through SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230581/cant-get-sql-server-to-start-or-connect-to-my-local-database-engine-through-ssm)

Pay attention mainly to the part about the registry.

If you have no luck here you may have to uninstall and reinstall Sql Server.

I appreciate that this is NOT the answer you were looking for, however it IS the only answer available.

Please consider this answer as acceptable and mark it as such then follow through with the suggestions made in the other question.

If you are still having no luck then your best bet is to raise a new Stack Overflow question specifically about the problem as it stands there and then.

Comment: Sorry for not being more detailed - the only change made is upgrading to Win10 - worked fine with Win7Pro.  I can log onto my server database and I can "see" my localdb but when I select that server I get the cannot connect error.  I'm using Mgt Studio ver12.0

Comment: Can you post some more meaningful errors? (After the failure press the "Show technical Details" button and paste the exception stack trace here) Also please respond with the EXACT (to the letter) versions of Sql Server you currently have running locally.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the help.  I've disabled my firewalls.  The named instance worked before upgrading to Win10 and I get this error message .. 

Cannot connect to R850-PC.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.2269.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.10240.16384
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.10240.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.10240

Comment: Here's the versions from the help menu ... Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.10240.16384
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.10240.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.10240

Comment: And just to confirm, from the Studio Connect to Server, I am selecting my LocalDB that used to run.  If I pick my Server database it connects but not to my local any more - I reinstalled Studio but still no luck :( .... dang.

Comment: Sorry - just reread your comments (SO comments are a bugger to read sometimes).

Comment: Totally misunderstood what you were saying so I deleted my original comments. My bad.

Comment: I still need though the exact version of Sql Server you had installed. Can you use this to tell me what version  of the engine you have installed, please? http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2011/06/27/find-sql-server-version-details-from-the-registry/

Comment: I'm definitely trying to connect to the Server Type = Database Engine and do not have Analysis Services selected.  I want to load my MDF files ... C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Can you open up the ERRORLOG file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log and tell me what it says in there, please? Got your version now so we're getting closer...

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of the ERRORLOG file if you can.

Comment: Here ya be!! .. 2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) 
 Jun 10 2015 03:35:45 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10240: )

2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      UTC adjustment: -7:00
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Server process ID is 8736.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      System Manufacturer: 'TOSHIBA', System Model: 'TECRA R850'.

Comment: Comments box is too small - can you update the question with it, please?

Comment: not sure how to do that ... here's my email DaveInVictoria@outlook.com :)

Comment: Just add it as an answer then.

Comment: Dave, is there a reason why you've not closed this and marked my answer as acceptable? I put a huge amount of effort into this and some magic beanz that my way come from marking the answer as acceptable would go a long way to making up for the time I spent looking at this these last couple of days...

Answer (score 0):

2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) 
    Jun 10 2015 03:35:45 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 10240: )

2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      UTC adjustment: -7:00
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Server process ID is 8736.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      System Manufacturer: 'TOSHIBA', System Model: 'TECRA R850'.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      The service account is 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2015-09-20 12:59:48.56 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
     -m "SqlSetup"
     -T 4022
     -T 4010
     -T 1905
     -T 3701
     -T 8015
2015-09-20 12:59:49.30 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.30 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.30 Server      Detected 4045 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.30 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.37 Server      Default collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2015-09-20 12:59:49.40 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.41 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2015-09-20 12:59:49.41 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2015-09-20 12:59:49.41 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 1388 at 20/09/2015 11:38:59 AM (local) 20/09/2015 6:38:59 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.42 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.42 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.44 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.44 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.44 spid7s      Warning ******************
2015-09-20 12:59:49.44 spid7s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.45 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.53 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2015-09-20 12:59:49.72 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.
2015-09-20 12:59:52.52 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:52.60 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.12 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2015-09-20 12:59:53.27 spid7s      Server name is 'R850-PC'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.77 spid14s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.85 spid14s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
2015-09-20 12:59:53.86 spid14s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.88 spid14s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.88 Server      SQL Server is attempting to register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:53.88 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/R850-PC ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.
2015-09-20 12:59:55.69 spid16s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.27 spid18s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.27 spid16s     Starting up database 'NOP36'.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.27 spid20s     Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.27 spid19s     Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.27 spid11s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2015-09-20 12:59:56.49 spid11s     The resource database build version is 12.00.2000. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 12:59:58.00 spid11s     Starting up database 'model'.
2015-09-20 12:59:58.23 spid11s     Clearing tempdb database.
2015-09-20 12:59:59.33 spid11s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2015-09-20 12:59:59.76 spid7s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 13:00:00.75 Logon       Error: 18461, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2015-09-20 13:00:00.75 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\ReportServer'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT: ]
2015-09-20 13:00:01.78 spid7s      .NET Framework runtime has been stopped.
2015-09-20 13:00:02.44 spid7s      SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-09-20 13:00:02.45 spid7s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Comment: Updated the answer to request closure on this question as I have essentially answer why you were unable to connect. Using this question to continue the diagnosis may yield a poor response from other community members as the question is now a few days old. Create a new question if needed will provide you a greater opportunity of resolution. Good luck!