# SQL Server 2014 Express suddenly stopped working and not getting up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014-express

SQL Server 2014 Express was working well but don't know what happened suddenly on weekend it's not starting. I tried to run it manually but it's throwing below error message.

[image]

Error log file is as below:

```
2017-04-10 10:36:41.56 spid9s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.56 spid12s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.57 spid12s     The resource database build version is 12.00.2000. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.59 spid9s      1 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.60 spid9s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.60 spid12s     Starting up database 'model'.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.63 spid12s     Clearing tempdb database.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.76 spid12s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x80090331. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm. 
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm. 
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-04-10 10:36:41.92 spid14s     SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
```

I tried to google it but not getting any FIX. I don't want to use any custom SSL certificate or anything high end feature of SQL server. I just want to use it to collect data from my applications. Simple CRUD operations with stored procedures. Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong with SQL server. Any workaround also will work.

Comment: You probably tried this already but i have to ask. Do you try uninstalling and reinstalling sql server ?

Comment: @GuidoG yes I tried to do that and also tried to repair but no luck since four hours.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330614/sql-server-could-not-spawn-fruncm-thread) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230581/cant-get-sql-server-to-start-or-connect-to-my-local-database-engine-through-ssm),may help

Comment: @TheGameiswar thank you for your pointers but they didn't worked. Fixed by a solution finally. Putting it in answer for anyone in trouble like me.

Comment: Appreciate all of your support masters on SO for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by installing Cumulative Update from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51187)

If you are installing fresh copy, install SP2. Can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167)